# Error on Reading in a json file with Spark R

Tags: json, r, sparkr

I am trying to follow a tutorial in SparkR. I follow the setup as required. But as soon as I try the function "read.json(path)"  I get the following error:

```
"Error in invokeJava(isStatic = FALSE, objId$id, methodName, ...) : 
  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at      sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)..."
```

I am running R 3.3.2 and Java JDK 1.8 as requested in the tutorial.
 I attach images of the code and the results:

Is my Java being found, is it the right version?

The image is in R studio showing the code on the left and the console result on the right:

[image]

Comment: Is your `JAVA_HOME` being found? Was it added to your environment variables? For instance, `Sys.getenv('JAVA_HOME')`.

Comment: YES     Sys.getenv('JAVA_HOME')
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_112"

Comment: Abdou Will be very obliged if you can help.Spent whole day on this . Even tried to instll on other machine and get similar error when tryinfgto set the sc ie the connect to spark.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

The spark-submit or sparkR instance is there.

Using the hdfs//...path put the json file on the Hadoop hdfs:

```
hadoop-2.0.2\bin> hadoop fs -put "/example/../people.json" "/user/../people.json"
```

Then use

```
people <- read.df (sqlContext, "/user/../people.json","json")
```

to read the json and create dataframe 'people'.

Above steps worked for me after I made necessary changes in the example dataframe.R.